# Ng-Bootstrap Pagination in Angular 4

Tags: angular, pagination, ng-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the pagination in Angular 4 but it still doesn't work. I've used a service to subscribe to my data and output it in the html and i want to limit it by putting pagination in it. Here's my code below.

> ts

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  closeResult: string;
    products: any;
    subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private productService: ProductsService) { }
    page :number = 1;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.productService.getAll()
        .subscribe(
          (data:any) => {
            this.products = data;
          },
          error => {

          });
  }
}
```

> html

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let product of products">
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.desc }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.qty }}</td>
    <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
    <td>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<nav class="pull-right">
  <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">
    <ngb-pagination [collectionSize]="50" [(page)]="currentPage" size="sm"></ngb-pagination>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

you must do the *ngFor over a pageProducts

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of pageProducts">
    <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
     ...

//And in your module:
currentPage:number=1;
get pageProducts(){
   return this.products.slice((currentPage-1)*10,currentPage*10);
}
```

Comment: What happens to my subscribe data? How can i use this paginate to connect to my subscribe data?

Comment: You must be maintain the subscription of your productService (is this subscription witch fill "this.products"). Using a "getter" force angular to ask about "pageProduct" that is the responsible of give you only the items you want

Comment: Yes this.products is the “let product of products”. Can you edit your code and put my codes with your code. Thanks a lot

Comment: I'am a bit confussed about your answer. You must have: products;currentPage;get pageProduct(){..}constructor(..){}ngOnInit(this.productService.getAll().subscribe((data:any) => {this.products = data;}..